# Embed YouTube video into libGDX project

Tags: youtube, libgdx

I would like to embed YouTube videos to my application? I couldn't find anything about this topic. Are there any specified methods for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a seemly good solution here: https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-video It is a video rendering extension, that is under continuos development.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible with clear libGDX. It depends on platform where you develop the application.

If target is **Android**, you have to make another activity which is started from libGDx. There you implement webview, which will contain url of your youtube video. After pressing button (or whatever event) in libGDX application activity can be started and background will sleep.

Example of activity, which open dialog and create webView:

```
public class WebVideo extends Activity {

    private String url;    

    public WebVideo(String url) {    
        this.url = url;     

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();    
        WebView webview = null;    
        // if we have internet connection
        if (common.IsNetworkAvailable()) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);

            // initialize web view
            webview = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.widget_frame);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.getSettings()
                    .setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            webview.setBackgroundColor(color.black);
            // loar url of questionnare
            webview.loadUrl(url);
            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                        Bitmap favicon) {

                }
            });
        }
        // if we dont have connection, show dialog and end activity
        else {
            buildDialog(this).show();
        }    
    }

    // show alert dialog
    private AlertDialog.Builder buildDialog(Context c) {    
            //Maybe we want some alert dialog (implementation here)
            }
        });    
        return builder;
    }   

    private void finishActivity() {
        // some result after exit if we want    
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

If your target is **iOS**, I am sure that, there is similar handling of this.
**Html**: you should still open video in the same browser.
The crucial is **Desktop**, there to the best I know, is not possible fake it with some clear way.